# AS3 - how to put links into the app that google can index?

Tags: actionscript-3, seo, hyperlink

How should one place links in a Flash app such that google can index them?

If I have a textfield that renders html and the html contains a  tag, will google index that? how does google search for links in a flash app, and how does it get the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually SWFs are indexed. Read [this FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swf_searchability.html). They got a special Flash player which is used by robots to index stuff.

But as far as I know google doesn't get indexed much this way because MOST of flash sites are dynamic. You have to have actual strings of text embeded in your SWF to get indexed.

And I don't know if they fixed that or not but if you load XML data into SWF it got indexed separately. Which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: so, if i have hardcoded in my swf something like this: myTf.htmlText = '<a href="www.myLink.com">www.myLink.com'</a>' google will index it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, you should put whatever you want Google to index in your html file as swfs don't get indexed last time I checked.

Comment: This last time was veeeeeery long time ago.